# Swift Module map file not found

Tags: swift, xcode, frameworks, cocoapods, carthage

So I started converting the project from cocoapods to carthage and i started with cryptoSwift. I have done this a thousand times before but this time I got this:

```
    <unknown>:0: error: module map file '/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/name-ditwjskujinmcmbfwjaeagfywgvu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/CryptoSwift/CryptoSwift.modulemap' not found
<unknown>:0: error: module map file '/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/name-ditwjskujinmcmbfwjaeagfywgvu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/CryptoSwift/CryptoSwift.modulemap' not found
<unknown>:0: error: module map file '/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/name-ditwjskujinmcmbfwjaeagfywgvu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/CryptoSwift/CryptoSwift.modulemap' not found
<unknown>:0: error: module map file '/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/name-ditwjskujinmcmbfwjaeagfywgvu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/CryptoSwift/CryptoSwift.modulemap' not found
<unknown>:0: error: module map file '/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/name-ditwjskujinmcmbfwjaeagfywgvu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/CryptoSwift/CryptoSwift.modulemap' not found
<unknown>:0: error: module map file '/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/name-ditwjskujinmcmbfwjaeagfywgvu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/CryptoSwift/CryptoSwift.modulemap' not found
<unknown>:0: error: module map file '/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/name-ditwjskujinmcmbfwjaeagfywgvu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/CryptoSwift/CryptoSwift.modulemap' not found
<unknown>:0: error: module map file '/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/name-ditwjskujinmcmbfwjaeagfywgvu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/CryptoSwift/CryptoSwift.modulemap' not found
<unknown>:0: error: module map file '/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/name-ditwjskujinmcmbfwjaeagfywgvu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/CryptoSwift/CryptoSwift.modulemap' not found
<unknown>:0: error: module map file '/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/name-ditwjskujinmcmbfwjaeagfywgvu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/CryptoSwift/CryptoSwift.modulemap' not found
<unknown>:0: error: module map file '/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/name-ditwjskujinmcmbfwjaeagfywgvu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/CryptoSwift/CryptoSwift.modulemap' not found
<unknown>:0: error: module map file '/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/name-ditwjskujinmcmbfwjaeagfywgvu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/CryptoSwift/CryptoSwift.modulemap' not found
12 errors generated.
<unknown>:0: error: failed to emit precompiled header '/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/slappiOS-ditwjskujinmcmbfwjaeagfywgvu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders/the-Bridging-Header-swift_3GGM83YCQRDVU-clang_1Y97NZ8UJF7VF.pch' for bridging header '/Users/user/Documents/company/something/projectname/the-Bridging-Header.h'
```

The wierd thing about this is that i only get this for 1 scheme (i have multiple) but there are no difference between them what i can see.

Anyone know why this is?

Answer (score -2):

Xcode can't find linked framework.

Delete DerivedData. Spill over left shoulder. Reintegrate carthage. Carefully read how to integrate carthage to your project, it has some gotchas.